# Java Transformer outputs &lt; and &gt; instead of <>

Tags: java, xml, java-io

I am editing an XML file in Java with a Transformer by adding more nodes. The old XML code is unchanged but the new XML nodes have `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of <> and are on the same line. How do I get <> instead of `&lt;` and `&gt;` and how do I get line breaks after the new nodes. I already read several similar threads but wasn't able to get the right formatting. Here is the relevant portion of the code:

```
// Read the XML file

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();   
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();   
Document doc=db.parse(xmlFile.getAbsoluteFile());
Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();


// create a new node
Element newNode = doc.createElement("Item");

// add it to the root node
root.appendChild(newNode);

// create a new attribute
Attr attribute = doc.createAttribute("Name");

// assign the attribute a value
attribute.setValue("Test...");

// add the attribute to the new node
newNode.setAttributeNode(attribute);



// transform the XML
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();   
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes"); 
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new FileWriter(xmlFile.getAbsoluteFile()));   
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);   
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Thanks

Comment: can you show a small sample input and a small sample output?

Comment: There is no mention of either `<` or `>` in the above code. How are you injecting them?

Comment: Give us a clue! Show us some angle brackets...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

based on a question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592025/transformer-setoutputpropertyoutputkeys-encoding-utf-8-is-not-working):

```
public void writeToOutputStream(Document fDoc, OutputStream out) throws Exception {
    fDoc.setXmlStandalone(true);
    DOMSource docSource = new DOMSource(fDoc);
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
    transformer.transform(docSource, new StreamResult(out));
}
```

produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

The differences I see:

```
fDoc.setXmlStandalone(true);
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 8):

To replace the &gt and other tags you can use org.apache.commons.lang3:

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(resp.toString());
```

After that you can use the following property of transformer for having line breaks in your xml:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing `InputStream` instead of `Writer` to `StreamResult`.

```
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new FileInputStream(xmlFile.getAbsoluteFile()));
```

The Transformer [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamResult.html#StreamResult%28java.io.Writer%29) also suggests that.